# Spring Data JPA, how to get Connection used by the current transaction context

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

How do I get the `java.sql.Connection` used by the current transaction context? Or is the connection actually opened at the end of transaction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inject the entityManager then retrieve the current hibernate session

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
```

Then retrieve the jdbc connection from the session.

By using the doWork function you can actually retrieve the connection

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connectionToUse) throws SQLException {
    }
});
```